# convert ienumerable to class object

Tags: c#

Modifying existing code that previously returned 1 organization to return the 1 organization and ANY children

```
//original
//Organization organization = workshop.Organizations.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id == assignedOrganizationId);

Modified non-working:
Organization organization = workshop.Organizations.Where(o => o.Id == assignedOrganizationId || o.ParentId == assignedOrganizationId);
```

Error says it can't convert my ienumerable select to organization (which is a class)

I've tried creating a list etc, but I can't get the syntax just right....

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

This resolved my issue:

```
IEnumerable<Organization> organization = workshop.Organizations.Where(o => o.Id == assignedOrganizationId || o.ParentId == assignedOrganizationId);
```

Though i have a subsequent line of code that is now erroring....because of the change.

```
bool currentAutoAssignSetting = organization.AutoAssignedWorkshops.Any(w => w.Id == workshop.Id);
```

AutoAssignedWorkshops is now not contained in organization.  I'll keep moving forward, thx everyone

Comment: `IEnumerable<Organization> organization = workshop.Where(...`

Comment: You can't convert it. Try using something like `First` or `FirstOrDefault`, e.g., `workshop.Organizations.Where(o => blah blah).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Don't use `Where(...)` use `Single(...)` (or `First`, or `SingleOrDefault` or `FirstOrDefault` depending on your requirement)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I appreciate your comment, but I didn't believe.  I've tried changing Organization to a list but my syntax is off.  I've updated the main post, do you have feedback on the edit

Comment: @JoshuaBoyd: There is a missing dot in front of `ToList`

Comment: That got me over the hump, though i'm running into a subsequent error....thx fellas